# Get full URL to entry

Tags: calendar, events

I am trying to list upcoming events in Expression Engine. I have the following code:

```
{exp:calendar:events sort="asc" dynamic="no" status="current" event_limit="2"}
<p><a href="{url}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:calendar:events}
```

I am unable to retrieve the full path (www.domain.con/etc/etc). I have tried url_title in the href but it is just the name of the entry.

These entries belong to a channel called Calendar: Events if that matters.

What is the tag to get the full path to an Entry?

FYI based on the current data, the first entry should be:
http://www.domain.com/index.php/events/test-speaker-series/#john-smith

Answer (score 2):

You need to compose the URL for the entry yourself depending on template group and template you want to use.

Looking at the sample URL you posted, I assume it will be something like

> {path=events/test-speaker-series}#{url_title}

Comment: Okay, but the code above could (and is doing) retrieve entries from multiple template groups, what do I do in this case?

Comment: The entries are completely separate from template groups. You probably meant to say they are retrieved from multiple channels. You can use [{comment_url_title_auto_path}](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#comment-url-title-auto-path) or similar variable, or compose URL directly in this template by checking channel_id